# Python create custom NaN

Tags: python, nan

is it possible to create a custom NaN value in Python?

I know a bit about floating point representation and that NaN is a FP value with some special exponent. Therefore, each FP value with that special exponent is a NaN.

To be precise, what I want to do is:

```
x = make_my_special_NaN(int_seed)
assert math.isnan(x)
assert test_my_special_NaN(x, int_seed)
assert not test_my_special_NaN(float("nan"), int_seed)
```

The function which I called `make_my_special_NaN` should take an integer seed which can
be used to identify the special NaN value I have (if this is possible).

Having this, it should be possible to test if a given NaN value is the special NaN given that integer seed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need to know exactly what you need it to work for. numpy?? math(implied by your post) if you need math.isnan looks like it would take monkeypatching and `test_my_specail_NaN` would be fairly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `f` and `d` format specifiers in [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) will allow you to use any bit pattern you like.

Comment: more specifically, `struct.unpack('!f', '\x7F\x80\x00\x01')` will unpack to a `float` NaN with a significand of 1.  Replace the trailing 23 bits with anything but zero and you get a NaN.  Same for `double` except the leading portion is `'\x7F\xF' and the significand is 52 bits.